Problem with installing python library Ominzart
I am trying to download the omnizart library, but I keep on getting this error: Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
I tried installing all its dependencies individually with: pip install ffmpeg fluidsynth pysoundfile
This is the complete error message. It said that the Cython pacakge was missing at the end, but I downloaded it atleast thrice by now. It would be great if you guys could help.
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\vihaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-prt9nxta\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\vihaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-prt9nxta\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\vihaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-prt9nxta\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\vihaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-prt9nxta\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I tried downloading Cython, and three other dependancies. I also tried to do this in a virtual environment, but it still did not work.

Sometimes such issue is caused by some missing system libraries not documented as dependencies ... and you need the -dev versions of them on Linux to be able to install from source (Python 3.13 seems to install everything from source ... ).

so what would you suggest I do? Should I try manually downloading the files from online?

What does pip show Cython give you? What does import cython give you in the python REPL?

pip show Cython: Name: Cython
Version: 3.0.10
Summary: The Cython compiler for writing C extensions in the Python language.
Home-page: https://cython.org/
Author: Robert Bradshaw, Stefan Behnel, Dag Seljebotn, Greg Ewing, et al.
Author-email: cython-devel@python.org
License: Apache-2.0
Location: C:\Users\vihaa\OneDrive\Desktop\Vihaan\Tab Generator\my_venv\Lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

import Cython does not give me an error

Are you running installation as admin/root? In such case the libraries available for "user" are not available in Python (at least not on Linux). Is the same pip giving you an error installing than the pip which reports Cython as installed?

What happens if you install directly from source without pip?

This looks like another issue due to badly set up packages with "isolated build environments". When you do pip install it says up a new empty environment to install in. That environment doesn't have Cython. What you have installed in your main environment is completely irrelevant. Ominzart doesn't list Cython as a dependency so pip doesn't install it. Therefore it doesn't work

Guys, I realized the problem, we can run pip install Cython Omnizart so that cython is first installed then omnizart. But the problem is that omnizart is an ourdated library, and we are better off using libraries like basic-pitch or other better and up to date versions. Thanks for the help!
